# Angular 5 Get correct Observable type from http request (why is it always Observable<Object>?)

Tags: angular, observable, angular5, angular-httpclient, angular-observable

I'm having a little trouble getting the correct observable type from an http.get request. Here is the function I'm having trouble on:

```
getMovie(title:string, year:number): Observable<Movie> {
    const params = new HttpParams()
        .set('title', title)
        .set('year', year.toString());
    return this.http.get(this.moviePath, {params})
  }
```

As you can see I want to receive and Observable of the class `Movie` from my backend api using the parameters `'title'` and `'year'`. The problem is that the reponse always comes back with the type `Observable<Object>` and not `Observable<Movie>`.

I'm aware that I could create a new Movie instance giving it the properties recieved from the list. The problem with that is that my movie class has properties that are optional. Here is my movie class:

```
export class Movie {
  title:string;
  year?:number;
  imdb?:string;
  trailer?:string;
  reviewClip?:string;
  reviewSummary?:string;
  reviewScore:number;
  createdAt?:Date;
  bestWeek:boolean;
  bestMonth:boolean;
}
```

Does anybody know an easy way to get the response to be of the type `Observable<Movie>` instead of `Observable<Object>`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

May be you can try to typecast from json response.

An example

```
public getEmployees(): Observable<IEmployee[]> {  
        return this.http.get(this._repositoryURL)  
            .map((response: Response) =>

   { return <IEmployee[]>response.json() })  
            .catch(this.handleError);  
 }
```

Your code

```
getMovie(title:string, year:number): Observable<Movie> {
    const params = new HttpParams()
        .set('title', title)
        .set('year', year.toString());
    return this.http.get(this.moviePath, {params}).map((response: Response) => { return <Movie>response.json() })  
                .catch(this.handleError);
 }

 private handleError(errorResponse: Response) {  
        console.log(errorResponse.statusText);  
        return Observable.throw(errorResponse.json().error || "Server error");  
 }
```

Comment: Excellent answer, I didn't even know about typcasting (fairly new to angular and typescript though I'm really liking typescript). A couple errors (which you couldn't have known about). Angular 5 uses lettable operators so you have to pipe the map operator. My reponse is already in the form of json so I took that off (you couldn't have known that). And last, your error handler was thowing me this message `ERROR in src/app/movie.service.ts(40,54): error TS2339: Property 'error' does not exist on type 'Promise<any>'.` so I removed it. Other than that, awesome! 
`

Comment: I'm having the same issue with the error handler. Would love to know how to do it with error handling somehow.

Answer (score 6):

> If you are using **HttpClient & Http**,It will return you automatically
>   Observable.

**So modify your code as**

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { Observable } from 'rxjs/Observable'
import { HttpClient,HttpHeaders,HttpResponse,HttpParams } from '@angular/common/http';

import { environment } from '../../../../environments/environment';
import { Movie } from '../models/movie'


@Injectable()
export class MovieService {

  constructor(private http:HttpClient) {

   }

  getMovie(title:string, year:number) {
    const params = new HttpParams()
        .set('title', title)
        .set('year', year.toString());
    return this.http.get<Movie>(this.moviePath, {params})
  }
}
```

> This will give you response of type Movie

Comment: In the question I specified that I was already recieving an Observable. My problem was that I wanted the Observable to be of a particular type. Thanks though